# Block request in Sails (via CORS settings)

Tags: cors, sails.js

I want to restrict/block request that comes not from my domain where app is running. As an example I want to disable POST request on `/contact` that comes from `Postman`.

So I thought it is a job for `CORS` configuration in sails and I did described my route as following:

```
'POST /contact':                            {
    controller: "ContactController",
    action: "contact",
    cors: {
        origin: "http://some-domain.com"
    }
}
```

What I expected is that only requests that come from `some-domain.com` will be accepted, others, as well as my test one from `Postman` will be rejected.

Unfortunately if I open postman app and try to make a POST request to `/contact` it will be accepted.

What am I configuring wrong?

Answer (score -2):

You need to [set securityLevel to 2](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/security/cors#?configuring-cors-for-individual-routes).